# Check list of apps instaleld on device and find the package name of my app?

Tags: android

I am trying to find the package name of my application by providing the app name. Below approach is taking very long time on Droid3. How can I optimize this or am I missing something?

```
 String                     sPackageName        = null;

   PackageManager           pm                  = m_Context.getPackageManager();

 //get a list of installed apps.
  List<ApplicationInfo>     packages            = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

  ApplicationInfo   ap  = new ApplicationInfo();
  ap.loadLabel(pm);



   for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {

        String          sApp                = packageInfo.loadLabel( pm ).toString();

        //Log.d(TAG, "Installed AppName = " + appName + "  ,package :" + packageInfo.packageName );
        //Log.d(TAG,   "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 

        if( sApp.compareTo( sAppName ) == 0 ){

            sPackageName    = packageInfo.packageName;
            break;
        }

   }// the getLaunchIntentForPackage  

   return sPackageName;
```

Thanks,
DK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `loadLabel()` to find package name, just get `packageName` directly from `ApplicationInfo` or `ResolveInfo` and compare it.

Using `loadLabel()` or `loadIcon()` is quite time-consuming.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case, I have the 'Application Name', and based on this, I need to find out whether this application is already installed on the device, if YES, then extract the 'Package Name'. How do I do this with your suggestion?